# View Controller is not showing with Container View in XCode 8 StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm building an app which using storyboard and designing view controller using container view. When i first designing, everything seems fine. But after i quit and restart the xcode, this problem is occurred like in image.
[image]

The View Controller is missing but the segue still exist, I have found out that somehow the view controller just hide somehwhere and if I delete the segue, the VC will show up again.
Is this a bug or somehow i screw up my XCode?
Thank you.

Comment: You should file a bug with apple.  What build # of Xcode 8 were you using?  Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Xcode 8.1, no, it's still there, and i'm getting used to the pain

Comment: Xcode 8 and bugs, who would've thought :)

Comment: @chronycles, if my answer below is correct, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an Xcode bug.  Lot's of bugs appeared in Xcode 8.  [Filing a bug report with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) and updating to the newest version (even if it's a beta build) looks like the only solution for this.